# how does numpy.where() method handle the equality condition when the array element and target are not the same data type

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, equality

I have a long list and its element type is int. I want to find the index of element that equals to a certain number and I use `np.where` to achieve this.

The following is my original code,

```
# suppose x is [1, 1, 2, 3]
y = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)
idx = list(np.where(y==1)[0])
# output is [0, 1]
```

After inspecting the code after some time, I realize that I should not use `dtype=np.float32` because it would change the datatype of y to float. The correct code should be the following,

```
# suppose x is [1, 1, 2, 3]
y = np.array(x)
idx = list(np.where(y==1)[0])
# output is also [0, 1]
```

Surprisingly, these two code snippet produce exactly the same result.

### my question

My does the condition for test of equality is handled in `numpy.where` when the datatype of array and target are not compatible (int vs float, e.g.)?

Comment: `>>> 1 == 1.0 ... True` but in general, you shouldn't depend on `np.where` for floats (what with floating point inaccuracies). Use `np.isclose` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know when this equality test will break.

Comment: Whenever the floating point number in question has no exact representation in memory, I suppose?

Comment: Perhaps there is threshold, if the absolute difference between array element and float target exceeds the threshold, the equality test will break. I can not find  how `np.where` is implemented.

Comment: The interpreter first does the `y==1`, and then passes the resulting boolean array to `where`.  `where` just looks for non-zero (True) values. So the key is in how `numpy` performs the equality test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy where (source code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d233e1f4c176de8b1bf1365aac48caa10610a402/numpy/ma/core.py#L7108)) is not concerned with the comparison of data types: its first argument is an array of `bool` type. When you write `y == 1`, this is an array comparison operation which returns a Boolean array, which is then passed as an argument to `where`.

The relevant method is [`equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.equal.html#numpy.equal), which you implicitly invoke by writing `y == 1`. Its documentation says:

> What is compared are values, not types.

For example,

```
x, y, z = np.float64(0.25), np.float32(0.25), 0.25
```

These are all of different types, `(numpy.float64, numpy.float32, float)` but x == y and y == z and x == z are True. Here it is important that 0.25 is exactly represented in binary system (1/4).

With

```
x, y, z = np.float64(0.2), np.float32(0.2), 0.2
```

we see that x == y is False and y == z is False but x == z is True, because Python floats are 64-bit just like `np.float64`.  Since 1/5 is not exactly represented in binary, using 32 bits vs 64 bits results in two different approximations to 1/5, which is why equality fails: not because of types, but because  `np.float64(0.2)` and `np.float32(0.2)`  are actually different values (their difference is about 3e-9).

Comment: why do comparison between int and float evaluated to `True`? `int 1` and `float32 1.0` have different representations.

Comment: Because it's about values, not the structure of internal representation of those values. If a and b are numeric NumPy types, exactly one of a < b, a > b, and a == b must evaluate to True because this is how numbers work. One could have designed  `equal` method so that it enforced values being the same type, but NumPy developers made a different design decision.